# Probability of Cholesterol levels

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

If the **mean serum cholesterol level is 217** and the **variance is 750**, then what is the probability that a randomly selected person would have:

A. Cholesterol value  **between 150 and 250**

B. **Greater than 250**

C. **Less than 150**

What I did was:

A. Pr(Y<250)= 250-217 / 27.3861 = 1.2049 --> 0.8849 (z table)

Pr(Y<150)= 150-217 / 27.3861 = -2.4465 --> 0.0071

Then, Pr(150< Y<250)= 0.8849-0.0071= 0.8778

Does it look correct? I think the final answer is a little too high...

B. 1- 0.8849 (from problem A) = 0.1151

C. Pr(Y<150)= 0.0071, as it was in part A.

Does it look right?

Comment: Numbers look OK to me. There are some deficiencies in the writeup, you use $=$ in an incorrect way. For example, you write "Pr(Y<250)= 250-217 / 27.3861." The probability that $Y$ is less than $250$ is certainly not equal to $(250-217)/(27.3861)$.  You have assumed normality, and are probably expected to do so without comment. Makes me shudder a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you assume a normal distribution then you calculations look correct, subject to very small precision issues.  Checking using R gives

```
> pnorm(250, mean=217, sd=sqrt(750)) - pnorm(150, mean=217, sd=sqrt(750)) 
[1] 0.8786837
> pnorm(250, mean=217, sd=sqrt(750), lower.tail=FALSE)
[1] 0.1141037
> pnorm(150, mean=217, sd=sqrt(750), lower.tail=TRUE)
[1] 0.007212658
```

In reality, it seems from [Google Images](https://www.google.com/search?q=distribution%20of%20serum%20cholesterol%20level&source=lnms&tbm=isch) that the distribution is right skewed, so a normal distribution is not exactly correct and the true probabilities will differ from these numbers.